# RE2 library C# wrapper

Tags: c#, re2

I can't manage to build the Re2.net project from the link: https://github.com/0xcb/Re2.Net
I tried to build it in VS 2010 and VS 2012, but it gives me linker errors and I got stuck.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: What _"linker errors_" does it give you?

Comment: What are the linker errors?

Comment: Well I tried to follow these steps described in the Regex.h header: C++/CLI Notes:
 *
 *  [+] C++/CLI can't target .NET v3.5 using msvcr100, even though it
 *      claims to in 'Project -> Properties'. VC++ 2008 (msvcr90) with the
 *      libraries extension feature pack is required to link to RE2.
 *      
 *  [+] VC++ 2008 SP1 is required to fix a linker error.
 *
 *  [+] VC++ 2008 hotfix KB976656 is required to fix a compiler error with
 *      using managed object methods.
 *

Comment: *  [+] '$(FrameworkSdkDir)lib\x64' is added to 'Library Directories' in
 *      'Project Properties -> VC++ Directories' for the x64 Platform.
 *      Otherwise Visual Studio can't find it when compiling under msvcr90.

Comment: And I also added the re2.lib from the Windows port re2 library in Porperties->Linker->Input

Comment: Sadly compiling C++/CLI is often quite ugly :-(

Comment: Have you installed VC++ 2008? Because it seems to be a prerequisite